# Tableau TabCMD without -u/-p attributes

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I am trying to create a SQL Server Agent Job that passes a tabcmd command to a remote Tableau server. I am hoping to use `refreshextracts` without explicitly passing a -u or -p attribute and, instead, use the AD account of the SQL Server Agent Service...

In short, can I use tabcmd with inherited permissions/access from Active Directory, rather than passing explicit username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, this functionality is not possible.

If it's a feature you'd like to see in the product then please create an Idea in the Tableau Community for other customers to see and vote on.